# Android studio : can't rename a package to add subname

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, rename, package-name

I want to renanme a package from `com.myexample.demo` to `com.myexample.demo.sub1` in android studio ,
I chose refactor --rename , I got `com.myexample.sub1`.
But I really want to get `com.myexample.demo.sub1`.

need your help!

Comment: i have a application ,the packgage name is com.myexample.demo ，
i want to rename the package name  ，to be com.myexample.demo.sub ，

but i refactor the package name in android studio，

i rename the name .i just to com.myexample.sub， not com.myexample.demo.sub

sorry my english is so bad